# Pick up a Darboux chart

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

I'm stuck with the following statement in the book Morse Theory and Floer Homology written by Audin(Proof of Proposition 6.1.6):

> If $W$ is a compact symplectic manifold and $H\colon W\to\mathbb{R} $ is a Hamiltonian wichi his $C^2 $-sufficiently small, then there is a finite cover of Darboux charts such that

- Every closed orbit of period $1$ of the Hamiltonian flow $X_H $ is contained in one chart;
- We have $\Vert dX_H \Vert <2\pi $ on every chart.

Comment: Maybe this is sort of backwards, but you can take the second bullet point as your hypothesis of $H$ being "$C^2$-sufficiently-small". Then by some Fourier-Analysis one can show that a $1$-periodic orbit of $X_H$ is necessarily constant, i.e. $x(t)=x \in W$ for all $t \in S^1$. Then the first bullet point is trivially satisfied.